# What is the maximum number of docs that can be saved in a single database in CouchDB?

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb, document, couchdb-2.0

1. What is the maximum number of docs that can be saved in a single database in CouchDB?
2. What is the maximum size of a single database in CouchDB?

I need to save millions of documents in a single database in CouchDB. So I want to know If there is a maximum limit so that It won't create any problem while searching for a document using views.

Comment: There's no hard coded limit. But you may begin to experience performance degredation at some point, which is probably impossible to predict. It will depend on your hardware, data structure, indexes, etc.  Is it working well enough for you now?

Comment: No, It is not. I need to upload 50 million docs in one database, but the process is crashing  even before it reaches 1 million. And Yes, I am using a server with pretty decent specs.

Comment: I'd focus on why it's crashing. What do the logs say?

Comment: It was crashing because the cpu was exhausted. I'm trying to limit the simultaneous numbers of bulk inserts and try it.

Comment: No, that's not why it crashed. "CPU exhaustion" isn't a thing. Unless you literally mean the CPU overheated, in which case you have a clear resolution: Get non-faulty hardware. Look at your actual logs. What reason does it give you for the crash?

Comment: This was the error which was coming repeatedly in couchDb logs : `fabric_worker_timeout update_docs`. And when I checked the cpu usage I could see that all cores of the cpu was used to 100%.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: CentOS 7. I think it was crashing because the request getting timeout. I'm getting 504 gateway timeout responses from Couchdb.